# Showing isomorphism between quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f: R_1 \rightarrow R_2$ be a surjective ring homomorphism.

Let $I_1$ be defined: $I_1=\{r_1\in R_1| f(r_1)\in I_2\}$, and I've showed that $I_1 \lhd R_1$. It's also known that $I_2 \lhd R_2$.

Prove: $R_1/ I_1 \cong R_2/I_2$

Can I just define an isomorphism?

Comment: Or simpler: $\;g:R_1\to R_2/I_2\,,\,\, r_1\mapsto f(r_1)+I_2\;$ .This is clearly surjective (why?) and $\;\ker g=I_1\;$ (why?), so now apply the first isomorphism theorem.